# Weird behavior related to float and margin

Tags: html, css, position

The problem is the position of the div with the `.parent` class. It is not at the top of the window, but is 100px below, which is exactly the value of `margin-bottom` of `.child`.

Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Here is my HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .parent {
            }
            .child {
                margin-bottom:100px;
            }
            button {
                float:left;
                height:30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child">
                <button>click me!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "element.div.parent is not at the top of the window"? I'm not seeing any content.

Comment: The float is causing it, but not sure why.

Comment: I think this due to margin-collapse + not being a BFC root.

Comment: Try putting a `position:relative;` on your `body` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

That's caused by ***incompletely*** handling **[floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)** and **[not mastering Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)**

> **Margin Collapsing on Empty blocks**
>   If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

You need to get rid of floated elements issues using `overflow:auto;` on the **parent** or
by **clearing your floats** i.e: [using a class](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/):

```
.clear:before,
.clear:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clear:after{
    clear: both;
}
```

---

*NB:* Using **background colors** will help you to target such issues in the future:

> "A parent has no visible background-color?" **99% a float issue!**

### Collapsing margins Issue:

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: gold;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
button {
  float:left;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        <button>Left floated Button</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

we have **Collapsing Margins** since `.child` **has no (non-floated) Content or any set `height`** to add-to it's box model so **`button` collapsed to the nearest available space - floating left.**
By just adding `height: 1px;` or just a text character inside `.child` you'll see the *collapsing issue* "fixed".

### Clearing floats

using our `.clear` (or `overflow:auto;`) on the parent:

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: gold;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
button {
  float:left;
  height:30px;
}

.clear:before,
.clear:after{
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clear:after{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent clear">
  <div class="child">
    <button>Left floated Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can see that the `.parent` added context/content thanks to the `.clear` hack creating a wrap for the `.child` and the floated button. `Parent` is now only aware of the `.child` 100px margin cause `.child` still has the collapsed margins issue.

Still no visible `child's` gold background? = We need to apply `.clear` (or again overflow) to it too!

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
}
.child {
  background: gold;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
button {
  float:left;
  height:30px;
}

.clear:before,
.clear:after{
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clear:after{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent clear">
  <div class="child clear">
    <button>Left floated Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

So, to recap what was happening:

- the `.parent` and `.child` could not handle the `float`ed element therefore losing "height" collapsing to *nothing* since **no other Content** is present.
- You can now imagine two thin elements (with no height) holding a floated button with `.child` being the only adding some 100px space with `margin-bottom` and pushing the floated element underneath that space (since floated) causing Collapsed Margins on empty blocks
- → by just adding any fixed `height` to `.child` you'd see the floated element *hop* in the right place (at the child's top) since the *new* available space and un-collapsed margins.

[Here's a good article about floats and related issues caused by floated elements](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)